# Consuming webservice from multiple sources and save to Db

Tags: python, django

I am building an application in django that collects hotel information from various sources and format this data to a uniform format. There after I need to expose API to allow hotels access to web apps and devices using django-rest-framework.

So For example if I have 4 sources

[HotelPlus, xHotelService, HotelSignup, HotelSource]

So please let me know the best implementation practice in terms of django. Being a PHP developer, I prefer to do this by writing a custom third party services implementing an interface so adding more sources becomes easy. That way I only need to call execute() method from the cron task and rest is done by the service controller (fetching feed and populating it in database).

But I am new to python django, so I dont have much idea of creating services or middleware is a right fit for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fetching data from the sources you will need dedicated worker processes and broker so that your main django process won't be blocked. You can use [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) for that and it already supports django.

After writing the tasks for fetching and formatting the data, you should need a scheduler to call this tasks periodically. You can use [celery beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) for that.